# PHP Variable in Jquery Reference

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

is it possible to use a PHP variable for Jquery animate.

For example would the following work `$('#boat').animate({'left','<?php=$percent ?>%');`

Comment: Instead of asking if it would work, why not just try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you output in PHP will literally become a part of the text when viewed by the client.

```
alert('<?php echo "Hello from PHP!";?>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Except for your incorrect shorthand echo syntax, the answer is "yes".

FYI, either use

```
<?= $percent ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $percent ?>
```

Note: The shorthand syntax prior to PHP 5.4 requires [`short_open_tag`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) to be enabled

To be super safe, I'd use `printf()`, eg

```
<?php printf('%.2f', $percent) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will. Just make sure the file you are using it in is a php file (.php extension)

Answer (score 0):

```
alert('<?php echo $variable_name ;?>');
```